# Angular width of first maximum in diffraction grating

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction

Often in my book they have referenced the fact that as $N$ (the number of slits) becomes very large, the angular width of the first maxima in a diffraction grating can be approximated as follows:
$$\Delta \sin\theta
\sim \frac{\lambda}{Nd} $$

I am wondering how to proof this statement, but cant make much progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is very much related to [Help understanding resolution between two light beams](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/470389/104696) which perhaps should be read first?

The first thing to remember is that in general the number of slits in a diffraction grating $N$ is very large so $N\gg 1$.

In the diagram below there are $N+1 \approx N$ slits of which only a few are shown.

[image]

For the $m^{\rm th}$ order the basic diffraction grating equation is $m\lambda = d \sin \theta_{\rm m}$ where $d$ is the distance between adjacent slits and the path difference between adjacent slits is $m\lambda$.

In my diagram the path difference between the slit labelled $A$ and that labelled $I$ is $Nm\lambda = IJ$ where $N$ is the number of slits in the grating.
The light from all slits in the grating constructively interfere and this results in a principal maximum in direction $\theta_{\rm m}$.

Now consider a change of direction by $\Delta \theta_{\rm m}$ such that the path difference between the light from slit $A$ and slit $I$ is $Nm\lambda + \lambda$. 
This would result in the slits in the bottom half of the grating and the corresponding slits in the top half of the grating, eg slit $E$ and slit $I$, producing waves which are half a wavelength out of phase and so interfere destructively.
This results in the first subsidiary minimum. 
The path difference between slit $A$ and slit $I$ could also be could also have been $Nm\lambda - \lambda$ and that would produce the first subsidiary minimum on the other side of the principal maximum.

From the diagram $AJ = D \cos \theta_{\rm m} = Nd \cos \theta_{\rm m}$.

For the triangle with angle $\Delta \theta_{\rm m}$ you have $\lambda = Nd \cos \theta_{\rm m} \:\Delta \theta_{\rm m}$ which then gives the result

$$\cos \theta_{\rm m} \:\Delta \theta_{\rm m} = \Delta (\sin \theta_{\rm m}) = \frac{\lambda}{Nd}$$

Note that this relationship gives the angular half width of a principal maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Using the grating equation (I'm replacing the $d$ variable with the $a$ variable for clarity)

$$a(sin(\theta^{'})-sin(\theta))=m \lambda$$

setting $m=1$,differentiating, and noting that the $\theta$ - the incident angle - is constant

$$ cos(\theta{'})d\theta{'}=d\lambda/a.$$

Dropping the prime on $\theta$ since there is only 1 angle of interest, and approximating the derivative with $\Delta$
$$\Delta sin(\theta) \approx \Delta\lambda/a.$$

Using the definitions of resolving power to find $\Delta\lambda$

$$R=\lambda/\Delta\lambda$$
$$\Delta\lambda=\lambda/R$$

and
$$ R=Nm$$

$$\Delta\lambda=\lambda/Nm$$
(noting that $m=1$) yields 
$$\Delta sin(\theta) \approx\lambda/Na.$$
Finally, replacing $a$ with $d$
$$\Delta sin(\theta) \approx\lambda/Nd$$